# Existing data model getting replaced while uploading a new rpd file?

Tags: obiee

when I upload a new RPD file in obiee12c existing data model getting replaced, if I wanna see the datamodel for multiple applications how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RPD upload does just that. It uploads an RPD. You work with multiple applications by having all those applications inside one RPD. Whether one source or 50 makes no difference at all to the RPD.

Comment: thanks for the the information, so If I export obiee instance as bar file, then will be only one file for rpd information right. can one OBIEE instance have multiple rpds's

Comment: No and no. BAR is RPD + Catalog + Security. And no, one instance of the OBI Server component is one RPD